# I know I'm way behind but .. is 10.7 stable for DAW ?

Tags: daw, osx

Hey a quick search on the ssd site doesn't return what I'm looking for.

I'm finally switching a PPC G5 rig over to an intel MacPro for Protools HD9 with a Magma chassis etc. Is 10.7 "generally" a stable platform for DAW / audio creative ?? I mean really general like yeah its good or no don't do it "XX_**_**_XX" is broken. Thanks

Comment: I never used Lion as I went straight from Snow leopard to mountain lion and nothing broke. OS wise it ran a bit smoother too. I'm currently on Mac 10.8.4 and Pro Tools Native 10.3.6.269.

Heck, Pro Tools is actually running very well. If that doesn't say its stable enough I don't know what will.

Answer (score 1):

see [10.6.8 vs 10.7 in regards to pro audio](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/18717/10-6-8-vs-10-7-in-regards-to-pro-audio/18728)

edit: also see: http://www.patentlyapple.com/patently-apple/2013/04/snow-leopard-remains-the-most-popular-version-of-os-x.html (3 apr 2013)

Answer (score 0):

I've been running 10.7 with PT10 on my core i7 MBP for over a year now without a hitch. I'd say it's stable.